# Default groups assigned to the first user in Ubuntu Server 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, user-management, groups, usermod

I just made a silly mistake on my Ubuntu Server box:  I added myself to a group using `usermod -G`, after which I discovered the `-a` option...

The result is that I am now out of the `admin` group, and lost my sudo rights.  I can sort that out, but I want to know what other groups I may been removed from?  My user was the first one so what I'm looking for is a list of groups that the first user gets added to at installation time.

Comment: For different Ubuntu versions: [Default groups for user in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/219083/1060743)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Michael's answer was the closest, but I wanted to be sure, so I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 8.04.2 (Hardy Heron) in a virtual machine to get the official group list.  The installation was a basic one with no specific server roles selected.  These are the first groups, assigned by default, to the first user:

- $USERNAME (e.g. wayne) (primary group - the rest are supplementary groups)
- adm
- dialout
- cdrom
- floppy
- fuse
- audio
- dip
- video
- plugdev
- sambashare
- lpadmin
- admin

To assign these groups to a given user, issue the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,audio,dip,fuse,video,plugdev,scanner,sambashare,lpadmin,admin
```

The `-a` switch means "append" so that existing supplementary groups are not overwritten.

To get a list of groups assigned to a particular user:

```
cat /etc/group | grep <username>
```

or for the current user:

```
groups
```

Comment: To get the groups of a user you can also do: 
groups <username>

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2007/07/02/restore-default-ubuntu-groups/), the default groups for the first user on an Ubuntu box are:

- $USERNAME (Primary)
- adm
- dialout
- cdrom
- floppy
- audio
- dip
- video
- plugdev
- scanner
- netdev
- lpadmin
- powerdev
- admin

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't have an Ubuntu box to verify this or know what version of Ubuntu these default groups belong to. It's a good starting point though.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

$USERNAME adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Comment: Exact same as for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, (which is in another answer), by the way.

Comment: Exact same? The answer for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has "disk". There is no "disk" in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS setup. Even if it's the exact same, I don't see providing the info as doing any harm :)

Answer (score 1):

The default group should be the same as the user name. So if you created user1, his default group would be user1.

[Edit]

[Here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=zGgZ850Aw5gC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=ubuntu+server+default+groups&source=bl&ots=6I0l9ywI_0&sig=u8FagNnOXt9vkCksRDRAXISBFRk&hl=en&ei=Fk0XSpDXKIaMtgeX4bneDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8#PPA109,M1) you have an explanation of the group memberships.

Comment: So just admin and the username?  Is that all for sure?

Comment: On a standard install that's all there is. At work we use Fedora and I know for sure that's all there is. And on my Ubuntu box here I only have my username and adm that I added after.

Comment: That guy's book is based on Ubuntu 7.10. Probably you have something different.

Comment: You're right. here are the groups I have on my desktop at the office: username adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare dev . It looks like I killed all the groups on my home box. I probably forgot the -a on a usermod too. I do that all the time, but usually I print out the groups I have before the usermod to be able repair any screw up I might make.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server 9.10 (samba, openssh instaled)

$username, adm, dialout, cdrom, plugdev, sambashare, lpadmin, admin

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

$USERNAME adm disk cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare